# TextView setText(String s) is not working?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-adapter

I have two `TextViews`. One of them is taking as a text parameter(`setText(String s)`) an object from `ArrayList` and the other one is taking a result of some calculations.

The funny thing is that the first one gets his text and the second one is empty.

Any ideas why?

Thank you in advance :)

Best regards, Dimitar Georgiev!

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

    textList = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listTextView);
    textList.setText(allFormulas.get(index).toString());
    textRes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.formulaSolve);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(textList.getText().toString() == "")
            {
                textList.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                ExpressionBuilder builder=new ExpressionBuilder(textList.getText().toString());
                Calculable cal=null;
                try {
                    cal = builder.build();
                } catch (UnknownFunctionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnparsableExpressionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                double d = cal.calculate();

                if(d == Math.floor(d))
                {
                    textRes.setText("="+Integer.toString((int) d));
                }

                else
                {
                    textRes.setText("="+Double.toString(d));
                }
            }

        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with this line:

```
if(textList.getText().toString() == "")
```

In java you cannot compare strings with `==`

Change this to:

```
if(textList.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use

> equals() method

for string comparison on the following line in the code

```
if(textList.getText().toString() == "")
{
    textList.setText("");
}
```

as

```
if(textList.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    textList.setText("");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Java we are using equal() method for comparing string

```
if(textList.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    textList.setText("");
}
```

but I think if you want accurate output you can use

```
if(textList.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    textList.setText("");
}
```

Thanks.